# Parse Identifiers from String containing code (Using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dynamic, metaprogramming

The problem I am trying to solve is this

#### Given a string containing code (entered by the user via some kind of web based form), such as:

> "a = b + 5; return Math.abs(a);"

#### Extract a list of tokens that are considered *identifiers*:

> **a, b**

In general are there readily available existing solutions? If not, what is a good starting point for writing an simple algorithm for this purpose?

I tried http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about, but was not able to find a method that readily returned the token type of an entire document. According to the API reference `getTokens(Number row)` should return the information I want. However, this method ended up returning the entire line as type `text`

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://esprima.org/ http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/ --- took me 10 seconds to google.

Comment: thanks, curious what terms did you use

Comment: @echen "javascript parser" in google

Comment: that was dumb of me ... i tried every combination of "parser" "javascript" "tokenizer" except the most obvious